# Show that the propositions $\alpha$ and $(Z\rightarrow\alpha) \wedge Z$ are equally satisfiable

Tags: logic

I already found that $\alpha \not\equiv (Z\rightarrow \alpha) \wedge Z$ but now I was ask to see if those propositions are equally satisfiable but I don't know how.
Hope someone can help me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I doubt it.  Couldn't you have $Z$ false and $\alpha$ true?

Comment: @GEdgar Ohhh I found that they are unequal fix it